# What is the best way to make these wire wraps around a mesh?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, wireframe, shrinkwrap

i'm trying to re-create this type of effect on a body mesh i have modeled
basically lots of metal curves wrapped around the mesh, most of them starting from the chest area (the center, core in the image)
the legs are more complex but i'm not doing that, just want the upper body to be shown.
is there a workflow i could use? i'm not too experienced in blender, i was thinking of curves or maybe particle system like hair, but i'm lost...

btw, it's just the model i want for now, if it's possible to animate it growing out it would also be cool, but i have a way of animating an already modeled mesh

[image]

Comment: there are many ways to approach this. you can use the "sculpt" tools withing blender. A different approach would be to use images as "bump" or "displacement maps". There is a lot of information on this site about those themes, use the **search** box at the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a "procedural" way to do it, but you could do it manually this way:

- Once your body is ready, create a second mesh (plane) over the body.
- Activate the *Snap* / *Face* mode, with all its options enabled.
- Begin to extrude your plane to make your straps. As the *Snap* is enabled, the vertices will stick to the body underneath.
- When you'll have finished you can add a *Solidify* modifier to give thickness, a *Bevel* modifier to make the angles round, then a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to smooth (+ press the *Smooth Shading* button on the *Tools* panel > *Tools* > *Edit* > *Shading*.
- Add some edge loops to your straps to give them more angular angles.

[image]